# Comparison semantics with std::atomic types

Tags: c++, atomic

I'm trying to find where the comparison semantics for the type `T` with `std::atomic` is defined.

I know that beside the builtin specializations for integral types, `T` can be any `TriviallyCopyable` type.  But how do operations like `compare_and_exchange_X` know how to *compare* an instance of `T`?

I imagine they must simply do a byte by byte comparison of the user defined object (like a `memcmp`) but I don't see where in the standard this is explicitly mentioned.

So, suppose I have:

```
struct foo
{
  std::uint64_t x;
  std::uint64_t y;
};
```

How does the compiler know how to compare two `std::atomic<foo>` instances when I call `std::atomic<foo>::compare_and_exchange_weak()`?

Comment: It doesn't "compare an instance of T".  The wording in the Standard is that it "compares the contents of the memory" occupied by your object, meaning the object type is ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In draft n3936, `memcmp` semantics are explicitly described in section 29.6.5.

> Note:  For example, the effect of atomic_compare_exchange_strong is
>       if  (memcmp(object,  expected,  sizeof(*object))  ==  0)
>           memcpy(object,  &desired,  sizeof(*object));
>       else
>           memcpy(expected,  object,  sizeof(*object));

and

> Note:  The `memcpy` and `memcmp` semantics of the compare-and-exchange operations may result in failed comparisons for values that compare equal with `operator==` if the underlying type has padding bits, trap bits, or alternate representations of the same value.

That wording has been present at least since n3485.

Note that only `memcmp(p1, p2, sizeof(T)) != 0` is meaningful to `compare_and_exchange_weak` (failure guaranteed).  `memcmp(p1, p2, sizeof(T)) == 0` allows but does not guarantee success.

Answer (score 0):

It's implementation defined.  It could just be using a mutex lock or it could be using some intrinsics on memory blobs.  The standard simply defines it such that the latter might work as an implementation strategy.

The compiler doesn't know anything here.  It'll all be in the library.  Since it's a template you can go read how your implementation does it.